# JsonProperty mapping to varying key

Tags: java, json, jackson, mapping, fasterxml

How can I map:

```
user: {
    #user1: "http:www.example.com/user1"
  }
```

To a class?

I tried:

```
public static final class User {

    public final String user1;

    @JsonCreator
    public User(@JsonProperty("#user1") String user1) {
          this.user1 = user1;
    }
}
```

The problem I ran into was that `#user1` changes. It might be `#user1` or `#user2` or contain multiple `#user1`, `#user2`, etc simultaneously.

This will result in:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field "#user2"

Comment: If the fields can change you might be better off mapping that to maps and arrays e.g. like json-simple does it.

Comment: Btw, what you you mean with "multiple `#user1`"? Would it be an array with that name that contains multiple strings, e.g. like `#user1: ["a", "b"]`?

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks. Swapped out the class for a `HashMap<String, String>` and it worked. It would be more like `user: { #user1: "abc", #user2: "xyz" }`

Comment: I see, that was a misunderstanding. In that case I'd settle for the list/array named `user` instead of optionally allowing for  `#user1` etc. which seems like bad design anyways.